# How do I put fill out this field in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

How do I put in my form.blade the "Please fill out this field" in every attribute?

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('title','Title:'); !!}
    {!! Form::text('title', null,['class'=>'form-control']); !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('description','Description:'); !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('description', null,['class'=>'form-control']); !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('stock','Stock:'); !!}
    {!! Form::text('stock', null,['class'=>'form-control']); !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('category_id','Category ID:'); !!}
    {!! Form::select('category_id', $categories, null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Choose a Category']); !!}
</div>

    {!! Form::submit('Save',['class'=>'btn btn-success']); !!}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="form-group">
 {!! Form::label('title','Title:'); !!}
 {!! Form::text('title', null,['class'=>'form-control','required']); !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::label('description','Description:'); !!}
   {!! Form::textarea('description', null,['class'=>'form-control','required]); !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('stock','Stock:'); !!}
  {!! Form::text('stock', null,['class'=>'form-control','required']); !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('category_id','Category ID:'); !!}
  {!! Form::select('category_id', $categories, null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Choose a Category','required']); !!}
</div>
{!! Form::submit('Save',['class'=>'btn btn-success']); !!}
```

Comment: Thank you for this :) it helped. It just need to add 'required' HAHAHAHA